# Classic Asp How do I save generated HTML to a text file on server?

Tags: javascript, html, asp-classic

Is there a way to save the current page´s HTML content into a text file on server?

Scenario:
I have a classic ASP page that generates HTML(report tables and stuff), after the whole page is generated, I would like to save it´s HTML code into a file on server, so I can read it later.

Comment: Why not generating text file instead of generating html and save it?

Answer (score 0):

By replacing **response.write** by **f.write**, you can save the file on server instead of sending file to the browser, Where **f** is createTextFile Object:

```
<%
dim fs,f
set fs=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
set f=fs.CreateTextFile("c:\test.txt",true)
f.write("Your current html and asp codes goes here considering syntax which connects html strings and asp codes in classic asp")
f.close
set f=nothing
set fs=nothing
%>
```

if you want to save your current page into server by a human action, you can get entire you html content using (javascript) jquery and send it to an ASP file to save it in a file. So you have to add a javascript function and a form which sends the content:

```
    <html>
    <!--your entire page is here-->
    </html>

    <!--You should add these extra code at the end of html file:-->
    <a onclick="submitform();">Save the page by clicking here</a>

    <form id="myform" action="savefile.asp" method="post">
    <textarea name="body"></textarea>
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    // assuming you have included jquery in your project:
    function getPageHTML() {
      return "<html>" + $("html").html() + "</html>" // You can also add doctype or other content out of html tags as you need;
    }

    function submitform(){
    var content=getPageHTML();
    $("#mytextarea").val(content);
    $("#myform").submit()
    }
    </script>
```

and this would be the source of asp page naming **savefile.asp** :

```
<%
dim fs,f
set fs=Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
set f=fs.CreateTextFile (server.mapath("test.txt"),true)
dim body
body=request.form("body")
body=replace(body,chr(34),chr(34)&chr(34)) 'To escpase double quotes
f.write (body)
f.close
set f=nothing
set fs=nothing
%>
```

Comment: The problem is, I have several nested loops and if statements. Also I have HTML hardcoded and not generated, The page is a mix of normal HTML tags and HTML generated tags.
Is there any other way I could do this? Otherwise I will have to change all the html tags to asp tags with response.write.

Comment: Do you expect the server to save new html files automatically as you insert new data into database? or a human is going to save htmls on server and you want to make this process easier?

Comment: No, there´s no database, I simply generate HTML and I want to save this generated HTML to a file after the page has been generated.

Comment: OK! I have updated the answer. Please check again and consider my comments inside Edited answer.

Comment: Well, that´s what I have done before, but because of my company POST message limits, the HTML generated size goes beyond these limit. That´s why I can´t send the generated code through POST or GET methods.

Comment: I wonder if I could save this generated page to a cookie(I have no idea of cookies size limits) and then read this cookie and save it.

Comment: Cookies, Form submit, server objects, And best of all the AJAX can transmit data between pages. In my answer you can make an ajax call instead of submitting form to pass data to next page.

Comment: Ok, I´m not very fluent with AJAX, I´m going to give some thought about that.
I gave up using cookies because they only hold 4kb of data.